# handle Ajax GET/POST request in , nodejs, expressjs and Jade Template Engine

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, pug

i m working in project where i use NODE, EXPRESS, and JADE TEMPLATE ENGINE , and AJAX to reduce page loading but when i get the result from a GET request in AJAX , i want to use the returned data (the results) directly inside the JADE file (i see that handlebarjs has a function called DataTamplate to send data to handlebar file but i don't know how we do that in JADE 
so my codes is the following:

```
router.get('/index/newest', indexControllerXD.get_newest);

exports.get_newest = function(req, res, next) {
     async.parallel({
        offers_recption: function(callback) {
            const end = moment();
            const start = moment.subtract(1, 'days');
            var range = { "$gt": start, "$lt": end };
            receptionPlaceModel.find({ 'created_on': range }).exec(callback);
        }
    }),
    function(err, results) {
        if (err)
            return next(err);
        res.send(results.offers_reception);
    }
};
```

so i send the result to AJAX GET request like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.grid-cell-newest').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    RefreshGetAll();
});

function RefreshGetAll() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/index',
        success: function(results){

        }
    })

}
```

})

so i want to pass the results in success method to JADE file to use the data of results
i don't want to use the results object inside the success , it won't help me generate what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Still not clear with your requirement, but it seems you want to use results value in JADE template.

Did you try placing  #{params.results} in Jade template  if you are calling ajax in script section of your template.

Comment: thank's, what i want exactly is to use the results in ajax file (the results are the data received from the express route {same url inside ajax} directly in JADE template , i have ajax calls in separate file